# Друг, подруга, другиня

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Почему:

бог -> богиня;
герцог -> герцогиня;
монах -> монахиня;
граф -> графиня;

Но:

друг -> подруга, 
А не: 
друг -> другиня;
Или
подруг -> подруга?

Answer (score 3):

Слово [другиня](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/wordhistory/1006/%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F) существует (*устар.* женск. к друг; то же, что подруга, приятельница). Словари определяют его как устаревшее, архаичное.

*Если слово «подруга» употребляют повсеместно, то «другиня» — лексема чуждая. Странное второе слово встречается в «Журнале землевладельцев» 1858 года, но почему только «подруга» вошла в активный лексикон русского языка?*

Интересны рассуждения этого землевладельца, он удивляется, почему в русском языке есть слова «графиня», «героиня», «богиня», но нет «другини». Он не считает «другиню» синонимом «подруги» и «подружки», а наоборот, предполагает, что «другинями» можно называть в принципе всех женщин. Такая лексема встречается у Пушкина, Чехова, но в разговорной речи не прижилась.

Слово «подруга» образовано от существительного «друг» так же, как и «друзья», «дружить». Приставка «по» означает приближение, близость к чему-либо (сравните — «побережье»). «Подруга» — это именно близкий человек по духу, тогда «другиня» могла бы просто обозначать женщин, например, как обобщенное обращение «товарищи» или «ребята». Ведь все эти слова больше относятся к мужскому полу, а для женщин придумано только обращение «девушки». Не скажешь же незнакомому человеку «подруга, можно к тебе обратиться», хотя вариант «друг, можно у тебя спросить» вполне допустим в разговорной речи.

В общем, загадочны лингвистические процессы, возможно, через несколько десятков лет «другиня» войдет в обиход!

[Почему «подруга», а не «другиня»?](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/philological_maniac/pochemu-podruga-a-ne-druginia-5a322bafc89010b4a3edb24c)

Сегодня слово используется, но нечасто.

[Другиня, спутница, вдохновительница ЕЛЕНА РЕРИХ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCf02lvISQ0)
[О книге  Екатерины Козыревой «Другиня»](http://www.rospisatel.ru/iksanov-kozyreva.htm)

Comment: Вряд ли что-то подобное произойдёт, т. к. практически этим словом — дружиною — украинцы называют жену.